# how to delete an item in array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've a question about removing items from an meteor document.

First of all, my database schema:

```
{
    _id: "kun1",
    job_x ["20080101","20131204"],
}
```

Well, I want to delete the last item of the array job_x and

I tried:

```
Box.update( {_id: this._id} , {$pull: { job: -1 } } );
```

Comment: try `db.Box.update({_id: this._id},{ $pop: { job: -1}});`. **$pull** operator removes all instances of a value from an existing array, it doesn't remove a filed. You want to remove field **result150160** at all or receive an empty array?

Comment: I've edited the question. Two questions in one thread are bad. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongodb's [$pop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pop/) to remove an item from an array.  The value 1 will specify it is the last item to be removed.

```
Box.update( {_id: this._id} , {$pop: { job_x: 1 } } );
```